# I am having trouble understanding why I am not able to .map over the data I am return in the state that I set up in my React program

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am currently getting the error message `TypeError: movieData.map is not a function` which to me does not make any sense when I grab the data from the API it is an array of objects. I am loading the data from API in an `useEffect()` and loading once and setting it to the state that I want in the Promise.

What am I missing/not understanding about Axios and receiving data from it?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

// import Poster from './modules/Poster';

function Home() {
    const [movieData, setMovieData] = useState([]);
    // const [baseURL, setBaseURL] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=ae6887d6afcef7f295ee5ce27afa2389&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1')
        .then((res) => setMovieData(res.data))
        .catch(err => console.log)
    }, [])

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     Axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/configuration?api_key=ae6887d6afcef7f295ee5ce27afa2389')
    //         .then((res) => setBaseURL(res.data))
    // }, [])

    // console.log(movieData)
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Home Page</h1>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    {movieData.map((movie) => <div>{movie.title}</div>)}
                </Row>
            </Container>
            <img src={`http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${movieData.poster_path}`} alt="poster"/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: The `Axios.get()` call is **asynchronous**.

Comment: Can you try adding a condition check like, ```{movieData && movieData.map((movie) => <div>{movie.title}</div>)}```

Comment: @ManirajMurugan yes I've tried that already.

Comment: @MicahJohnson, Then can you just make ```console.log(movieData)``` before the above mentioned line and check whether you are receiving the array data??

Comment: You are not getting array in `res.data` because this error occurs when you try to use `.map` other than array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `console.log` the `res.data` you're getting back from your axios request, you'll likely find that it is an object, not an array.

You might perhaps want to use `res.data.results` to get the array of results. Or alternatively try mapping over `movieData.results` if you do want to store the whole object in state. If you're doing that though, you should probably provide a better default to state than an empty array.

Comment: Thanks Jon! I completely missed that I wasn't pulling resultS (because i tried result last night) and its works!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the movieData is array. Or the movieData definitely be null.